# Regex for url to match for particular suffix domain

Tags: python

It is a keyword ranking module. I need to search for the suffix domain including co.in,co.uk
I tried the below code but it is not working
The client domain for the code is:www.domain_name.com
The search lists all the url for the clientdomain

```
for j in search(s, tld="com|co.in", num=100, stop=1, pause=2):
        domain=urlsplit(j)[1].split(':')[0]
        if clientdomain == domain:
            b=c
            d=j
            h=str(now)
            o.append(b)
            m.append(d)
            flash(d)
            flash(s)
            flash(b)
            #print("The position of the google search result is:",b)
            #print("The full url:",d)
            #print("The keyword is:",s)
            #print("The date of search:",str(now))
        else:
            hasRank = False
        c=c+1
    c=0
if(hasRank == False):
        print("Uh oh, you're website is not ranked among the top 100 results. Sorry :-(")
```

I tried to use a regular expression but does not work

```
   import re
   clientdomain = "www.google.com"
   print (re.search("(www.?://[^\s]+)", clientdomain))
```

**output**
      None

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. your question lacks information. what is this `search`? what RE have you tried? what errors are you getting?

Comment: i did not get any error @Nullman

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the posted code. It is unclear which parts belong to the `for` loop and which don't.

Comment: Fixed the indentation @mkrieger1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not perfectly clear on what output you need, but this might get you started:

```
print(re.findall("\.(\w+)", clientdomain))
```

It outputs a list of all but the first (most likely 'www') sections of the url:

```
['google', 'com']
```